# The advance search is not working for “unbounded options” fields

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

In  WSO2 Governance registry (version 5.0.0), the advance search is not working for the scenario  involving  “unbounded options” fields. Here is a test case I tried.  Created a new artifact type with following field.  Artifacts list page renders fine.  Then through advance search page, searched for the criteria “subheadingOne=value1 AND subheadingone=value2” ,  search comes back with no items.

Any hint what I am doing wrong?
Where can configure the  interpretation of multiple values for an “options” field to be interpreted as “AND” vs “OR’ operation?

```
<table name="Heading" columns="3" maxoccurs="unbounded">
        <subheading>
            <heading>subheading One</heading>
            <heading>subheading Two</heading>
            <heading>subheading Three</heading>
        </subheading>
        <field type="options">
            <name>subheadingOne</name>
            <values>
                <value>value1</value>
                <value>value2</value>
                <value>value3</value>
            </values>
        </field>...         
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in 5.0.0 and it is being fixed in Governance Registry 5.2.0 simply using a the normal search bar.

Let's say users want to search subheadingOne which value1 they can simply run the following query,

```
heading_subheadingOne:value1

<table_name>_<filed_name>:<search_value>
```

[image: asset overview]

[image: search view]

You can only search by AND operator in GReg publisher and store. For that please find the below sample,

```
heading_subheadingOne:value2 heading_subheadingTwo:test
```

***In here the space denotes the AND operation.***

You can find more GReg 5.2.0 search keywords from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Searching+for+Assets+Using+Advanced+Search+Operators). If you want to see some sample queries please visit [this post](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/03/wso2-governance-registry-publisherstore.html).

you can download a nightly build of GReg 5.2.0 beta from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-greg/releases/tag/v5.2.0-beta).

Hope this helps.

Comment: tested it on "03-30-2016" build.  Sorry to report that apparently  the suggested search technique didn't work.  Even the use of wild character (heading_subheadingOne:*) to match any string is not getting any results. Still looking for the solution.

Comment: Did you built your own product-greg? Or from where did you get this pack?
Could you kindly paste xml content of a single asset? you can get that by login into the management console. 
Metadata>asset_type>asset>Standard view>Display as text

Comment: no, I used the build from wso2 download site. Here is the link to sample http://www.filedropper.com/wso2advancesearchtar Also I noticed that the search works only for first value from the dropdown or options.

Comment: We are releasing GReg 5.2.0 within next week therefore kindly find the beta pack from here. I have tested the same scenario in this pack and its working fine. 
https://github.com/wso2/product-greg/releases/tag/v5.2.0-beta

Comment: I think there are couple of issues. (1)The search criteria for option field(s) matches only the “first” value of  the field, instead of all values.  (2) Search service is considering only the last part of the search criteria. You can observe this behavior using my previously attached sample assets and specifying “heading_subheadingOne:value2 heading_subheadingOne:value3”  search criteria. Expected result is three assets but only one is returned.

Comment: From the attached samples it is worth noting  the definition of “subheadingOne” field: "<field type="options"><name>subheadingOne</name><values><value>value1</value><value>value2</value><value>value3</value></values> </field>". The field “heading_subheadingOne” for all three assets have all possible values (value1, value2 and value3)  in different “order”.  For the search criteria “heading_subheadingOne:value2 heading_subheadingOne:value3” expected result is all three assets, actual result has only one asset (sample 3) whose subheadingOne’s  first value is “value3”.